# Custom ViewBase Implementation For ListView

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Does anyone have any experience, thoughts or example code about implementing a custom `ViewBase` as used in `ListView.View` ?

To date, the only control in the framework that inherits from '`ViewBase`' is the `GridView`. I want to create something equally complex but not quite sure where to start. I have reflected many of the classes involved in the current `GridView` implementation, but none of it really makes any sense yet.
I have a sneaky suspicion that `ListView`, its '`View`' property and the `GridView` are more closely related than it would appear at first glance, and achieving my goal may not be possible in any practical sense (but this is just a hunch)

Comment: Usually you can do all you want by creating a custom template for an ItemsControl. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to create something similar to the columns collection as declared in the GridView. re-templating the items control wont take me far enough